# How to target Firefox browser specifically?

Tags: javascript, css, firefox

I have a font that renders certain characters incorrectly on Firefox. I want to change the font to something else if Firefox is detected. I tried this technique:

```
body:not(:-moz-handler-blocked) .altFont { 
  font-family: helvetica, arial, sans-serifs !important;
}
```

It didn't work and also on the Firefox site it says it's not recommended. I was wondering if there is any other way to check?

Answer (score 2):

Use the following syntax to target any version of Firefox Browser:

```
@-moz-document url-prefix() { 
  /* Styles to be executed on firefox */
  body .altFont {
    font-family: helvetica, arial, sans-serifs !important;
  }
}
```

Reference: [CSS hacks targeting firefox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-hacks-targeting-firefox/)